# Accessing API through R (sample instructions in java)

Tags: json, r

I'm attempting to access the API for simplybook.me in R. [Here are the instructions they give](https://simplybook.me/en/api/developer-api), which give a bit of a vignette in java for how to get started. I have turned on the API, and have permissions on the user side, but I cannot figure out how to use jsonlite or httr to access the api. I've gone through several iterations, but I'm not confident that I'm authenticating correctly, and I'm not confident I'm asking for the right things on the R side of it. The basics, I think, should start with something like

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

apikey="XXXX"
url.path=paste("https://user-api.simplybook.me/login",sep="")
rdin=GET(url.path)
content(rdin)$methods$getBookings$returns #only gives the text string "object"
```

But this doesn't return anything, just a text string.

The instructions in Java suggest

```
$loginClient = new JsonRpcClient('https://user-api.simplybook.me' . '/login/');
$token = $loginClient->getToken(YOUR_COMPANY_LOGIN, YOUR_API_KEY);
$client = new JsonRpcClient('https://user-api.simplybook.me' . '/', array(
    'headers' => array(
        'X-Company-Login: ' . YOUR_COMPANY_LOGIN,
        'X-Token: ' . $token
    )
));
```

But I'm incapable of translating this into R. I would appreciate anyone's eye

Comment: Do you know what the `$loginClient->getToken()` function does? How can R calculate the token value? Otherwise you can easily add headers with something likr ```GET(url.path, add_headers(`X-Token` = token))```

Comment: Thank you...the libraries that the vendor created are here [link](https://simplybook.me/api_example/json-rpc-client.js) After some more poking, I think (?) I have the the token, which was created through their GUI. But I still can't seem to extract actual data with the call, only meta-information about the data?

Comment: The add_headers syntax almost certainly got me closer though...thank you

Comment: now I'm here: 
`rdin=GET(url.path, add_headers(`X-Company-Login`="ourname",`X-Token`="tokenfromthegui"))`
But I can't extract actual data from here, only meta-information